# Free memory of byte[]

Tags: c#, memory-management

I'm currently struggling with memory usage in c#.

The tool I'm currently working on is able to up- and download files. For that it is using byte arrays as buffers for the file contents. After an up- or download operation I can dispose the WebResponse and the Stream(+Reader/Writer) objects, however the byte array stays alive in memory forever. It goes out of scope and I even 'null' it, so I guess the garbage collection is never running.

While searching, I have found lots of articles that suggest to never ever run GC manually, however having a minimalistic background app that constantly takes up 100 or even 1000 MB of RAM (which keeps increasing the longer you use it) is anything but decent.

So, what else could be done in such a case if the usage of GC isn't recommended?

**Edit 3 / Solution:** I ended up using a 16kb byte buffer that gets filled with data from file i/o. After that the buffer contents are written to the RequestStream and further actions (updating the progress bar etc.) are taken.

Edit 2: It seems to be related to LOH. I will do tests on friday and note the results here then.

Edit: this is the code, maybe I'm missing a reference?

```
    internal void ThreadRun(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        UploadItem current = Upload.GetCurrent();

        if (current != null)
        {
            string localFilePath = current.src;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(localFilePath);
            elapsed = 0;
            progress = 0;

            try
            {
                string keyString = Util.GetRandomString(8);

                worker.ReportProgress(0, new UploadState(0, 0, 0));

                FtpWebRequest req0 = Util.CreateFtpsRequest("ftp://" + m.textBox1.Text + "/" + keyString, m.textBox2.Text, m.textBox3.Text, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory);

                req0.GetResponse();

                FtpWebRequest req1 = Util.CreateFtpsRequest("ftp://" + m.textBox1.Text + "/" + keyString + "/" + fileName, m.textBox2.Text, m.textBox3.Text, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile);

                worker.ReportProgress(0, new UploadState(1, 0, 0));

                byte[] contents = File.ReadAllBytes(localFilePath);

                worker.ReportProgress(0, new UploadState(2, 0, 0));

                req1.ContentLength = contents.Length;

                Stream reqStream = req1.GetRequestStream();

                Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
                timer.Start();

                if (contents.Length > 100000)
                {
                    int hundredth = contents.Length / 100;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        worker.ReportProgress(i, new UploadState(3, i * hundredth, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds));
                        reqStream.Write(contents, i * hundredth, i < 99 ? hundredth : contents.Length - (99 * hundredth));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    reqStream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);
                    worker.ReportProgress(99, new UploadState(3, contents.Length, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds));
                }

                int contSize = contents.Length;
                contents = null;

                reqStream.Close();

                FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)req1.GetResponse();

                reqStream.Dispose();

                if (resp.StatusCode == FtpStatusCode.ClosingData)
                {
                    FtpWebRequest req2 = Util.CreateFtpsRequest("ftp://" + m.textBox1.Text + "/storedfiles.sfl", m.textBox2.Text, m.textBox3.Text, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile);

                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                    byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(keyString + "/" + fileName + "/" + Util.BytesToText(contSize) + "/" + now.Day + "-" + now.Month + "-" + now.Year + " " + now.Hour + ":" + (now.Minute < 10 ? "0" : "") + now.Minute + "\n");

                    req2.ContentLength = data.Length;

                    Stream stream2 = req2.GetRequestStream();

                    stream2.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    stream2.Close();

                    data = null;

                    req2.GetResponse().Dispose();
                    stream2.Dispose();

                    worker.ReportProgress(100, new UploadState(4, 0, 0));
                    e.Result = new UploadResult("Upload successful!", "A link to your file has been copied to the clipboard.", 5000, ("http://" + m.textBox1.Text + "/u/" + m.textBox2.Text + "/" + keyString + "/" + fileName).Replace(" ", "%20"));
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Result = new UploadResult("Error", "An unknown error occurred: " + resp.StatusCode, 5000, "");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                e.Result = new UploadResult("Connection failed", "Cannot connect. Maybe your credentials are wrong, your account has been suspended or the server is offline.", 5000, "");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you know the byte array is still alive in memory?

Comment: You must have a reference to the memory that you're not erasing. You don't have to erase the contents of the byte array, you have to remove all references to it and the GC will reuse the memory.

Comment: Some relevant code might help. It's possible you are doing something that is making it more difficult for the GC to reclaim the memory (like keeping a reference to it somewhere).

Comment: Are you sure it's the `byte[]` not being disposed? Have you used CLRProfiler to verify this? Have you tried using Windbg / SOS to find the references that's keeping the `byte[]` alive (if any)? Are you using some manual asynchronous I/O? Also, it's often a good idea to reuse the same `byte[]` buffers over multiple uploads/downloads - this will avoid the memory allocation / deallocation overhead completely.

Comment: Can you confirm whether running GC.Collect() manually succeeds in reclaiming the memory? (Just for diagnostic purposes of course). And also, how big do these byte arrays get?  That could be part of the problem.

Comment: Do you ever get OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: ***Show Code*** Show Evidence.   If you have evidence that the byte-array is alive in memory, that is also evidence that you are holding a reference to it.   That reference keeps it alive.

Comment: Okay, so here is the method: http://pastebin.com/2HTuUZW3

Comment: Thanks for the code; ideally you would include this inline in your question so the resources are all on-site.  Indenting it by at least four spaces will guarantee that it gets displayed as code with nice color coding, etc.

Comment: Is it possible that the queuing is happening faster than the uploading such that you get a backup of `UploadItem`s, that hold the byte arrays you're worried about?

Comment: @adv12 `UploadItem`s only hold the source path, destination path and a boolean whether the local file should be deleted or not. Nothing regarding the byte[] there.

Comment: @SamStanojevic apparently that doesn't seem to do anything. Now, I'm not really sure if it's the byte[] not being destroyed anymore... Depending on the file size, these arrays can get somewhat large (there is no real limit, but it tested it with 50 mb)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At the core, the problem is that you read from your file in one big chunk.  If the file is very large (greater than 85,000 bytes to be precise), then your byte array will get stored in the LOH (large object heap).

If you read up on the 'large object heap' (there is plenty of information on the topic if you google it), you will find that it tends to get collected a lot less frequently by the GC than the other heap areas, not to mention that it won't compact the memory either by default, which leads to fragmentation and eventually 'out of memory' exceptions.

In your case, all you need to do is read and write the bytes in smaller chunks, with a fixed-sized byte array buffer (e.g.: 4096), instead of trying to read the file all at once.  In other words, you read a few bytes into your buffer, then you write them out.  Then you read a few more into that same buffer, then you write it out again.  And you keep doing that in a loop until you've read the whole file.

See: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation on how to read your file in smaller chunks, instead of using

```
File.ReadAllBytes(localFilePath);
```

By doing this, you will always be dealing with reasonable amounts of bytes at any given time that the GC will have no problem collecting in a timely fashion when you are done.

Comment: Now that I'm using smaller `byte[]`s, the problem seems to be gone. This is the most informative answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Just write smarter code.  No need at all to load the entire file into a byte[] to upload it to an FTP server.  All you need is a FileStream.  Use its CopyTo() method to copy from the FileStream to the NetworkStream you got from GetRequestStream().

If you want to show progress then you'll have to copy yourself, a 4096 byte buffer gets the job done.  Roughly:

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(localFilePath)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int total = 0;
    worker.ReportProgress(0);
    for(;;) {
       int read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
       if (read == 0) break;
       reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
       total += read;
       worker.ReportProgress(total * 100 / fs.Length);
    }
 }
```

Untested, ought to be in the ball-park.

Answer (score 4):

The garbage collection is different for large objects - and only available with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and newer.

This code will free the large object heap:

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect();
```

See also:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: I hope you are not suggesting he should enable compacting the LOH to fix his problem. That would not be a good idea.

Comment: It depends. It's a quick solution that does not require many code changes.

Comment: @SamStanojevic I assume it's just for testing if it is only affected by the LOH issue. I will do some tests on friday and give feedback then.