# How do I save a large Texture2D to the disk, when EncodeToPNG() creates too large of a buffer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Texture2D which I would like to save to the disk as a PNG. Here is my code:

```
byte[] pbytes = texture.EncodeToPNG();
File.WriteAllBytes(path, pbytes);
```

This code exists in a for loop, where I'm saving large quantities of large images.

By using EncodeToPNG(), the data is stored in a large byte array. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622145/free-memory-of-byte) thread, this means the memory is stored in the LOH (Large Object Heap), and is freed less often. This becomes an issue when I need this memory to be freed immediately, so that I can allocate more for saving.

Currently, the memory is not freed, and my Unity application crashes after running out of memory. This behavior does not happen in the editor-- it only happens when I build the application into an executable.

Is there any way to solve this issue, possibly by reading the bytes in smaller arrays from the Texture2D?

Comment: What are you saying doesn't make sense you application can get slow when GC wasn't done but if you dereferenced something it will get cleared when needed. From what I know unity doesn't use the mono way of GC https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity4-1.html so this just doesn't make any sense. How large are the textures you are using? I am pretty sure you have a memory leak somewhere else and you should review the code first before blaming the GC.

Comment: You could always avoid any GC by creating your own serialization format using a NativeArray<byte> instead of a byte[] and then call dispose at the end. There's probably a simpler solution though. The problem isn't GC if your program is crashing because it doesn't have enough memory, GC would cause your program to hitch and slowdown, but not run out of memory --> in fact GC would make sure any non-referenced memory is being collected before the program runs out of memory.

Comment: If you really need to clean the GC immediately for some reason instead of letting it do its job on its own you can use [`GC.Collect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect#System_GC_Collect)